# Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' - SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am getting the following error at runtime.

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'scrcrdsController' method 
com.mastercard.qualityScore.controllers.ScrcrdsController#getSummary(String)
to {GET /api/v1/scrcrds/{id}}: There is already 'scrcrdsController' bean method
com.mastercard.qualityScore.controllers.ScrcrdsController#get(String) mapped.
```

I need to ccreate a new api which fetches all the scores of a particular id or maybe a combination of two id's.
How do I fix this? Please help.

My controller is as follows-

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/scrcrds")
public class ScrcrdsController {
    @Autowired
    private ScrcrdRepository scrcrdRepository;

    //list all scrcrd records
    @GetMapping
    public List<Scrcrd> list() {
        return scrcrdRepository.findAll();
    }

    //get summary  of an employee
    @GetMapping(value = "{id}")
    public List<Scrcrd> getSummary(@PathVariable String id) {
        return  scrcrdRepository.findAllById(Collections.singleton(id));
    }

    //get scrcrd record by id
    @GetMapping(value = "{id}")
    public Scrcrd get(@PathVariable String id) {
        return scrcrdRepository.getOne(id);
    }

    //create a new scrcrd record
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)  //to get  201 response instead of 200
    public Scrcrd create(@RequestBody final Scrcrd scrcrd) {
        return scrcrdRepository.saveAndFlush(scrcrd);
    }

    //delete a scrcrd record
    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable String id) {
        //Also need to check for children records before deleting
        scrcrdRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    //update a scrcrd record
    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public Scrcrd update (@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Scrcrd scrcrd) {
        //because this is a PUT, we expect all attributes to be passed in. A PATCH would only need what attribute is being modified
        //TODO: Add validation that all attributes are passed in, otherwise return a 400 bad payload
        Scrcrd existingScrcrd = scrcrdRepository.getOne(id);
        //attributes of emp are copied to existingScrcrd, emp_id, mgr_id, mgr_scr_dt and type_nam is not to be changed
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(scrcrd, existingScrcrd   , "emp__id", "mgr_id", "mgr_scr_dt", "type_nam");
        return scrcrdRepository.saveAndFlush(existingScrcrd);
    }
}
```

Comment: If a request arrives that matches `/api/v1/scrcrds/{id}`, which method should be called, `getSummary` or `get`?

Comment: *Unrelated:* Since you're using [`@GetMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html) and [`@PostMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html), why not use [`@DeleteMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/DeleteMapping.html) and [`@PutMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PutMapping.html)?

Comment: GET /api/v1/scrcrds/{id} has encountered 2 similar methods that are causing ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created two methods with the same GET request and endpoint, i.e `/api/v1/scrcrds/{id}`. The solution is to change endpoint for one of your requests either *getSummary()or *get()*. Here I have changed the endpoint for `getSummary()`.

```
    //get summary  of an employee
    @GetMapping(value = "summary/{id}")
    public List<Scrcrd> getSummary(@PathVariable String id) {
        return  scrcrdRepository.findAllById(Collections.singleton(id));
    }

    //get scrcrd record by id
    @GetMapping(value = "{id}")
    public Scrcrd get(@PathVariable String id) {
        return scrcrdRepository.getOne(id);
    }
```